# Can a guard have more than one result?

Tags: haskell

As a newbie to Haskell, thinking in a way that's idiomatic is a challenge. I have a list of dyads. I want to weight dyad members according to two maps, one indicating the direction of the weighting and the other providing the weighting itself. In the following code 1 indicates that the bottom member of the dyad receives the weight; -1 the top member of the dyad receives the weight; 0 that both members receive the weight. In all cases it is the difference between dyad members that determines the weight and direction

My question is how can I re-use the definitions for top and bottom weight allocation in the case where the weighting is equal? Every source I have consulted so far seems to indicate that guards can have only one outcome - which I suspect is the proper Haskell way...

```
allocateWeight :: [[Integer]] -> (Integer, Integer, Maybe Double)
allocateWeight [x, y]
    |direction <= Just 1 = assignBottom
    |direction <= Just (-1)  = assignTop
    |direction <= Just 0 = (?? assignBottom and assignTop ??)
  where diff = (abs(x!!1 - y!!1))
      direction = Map.lookup diff getWeightDirection 
      weight = Map.lookup diff schemaCAT
      assignBottom = (head x, last x, weight)
      assignTop = (head y,  last y, weight)
```

Okay Ive been asked to clarify further. Ill cut the non essentials as they will only cloud the issue.

Stage 1: start with a list of values eg: [6, 3, 8, 11, 2] : values constrained between 1 and 12.

Stage 2: permutate them into dyads: [(6,3),(6,8), (6,11), (6,2), (3, 8), (3, 11),(3, 2),(8, 11)(8, 2),(11,2)]

Stage 3: Get the absolute difference of each pair:[(3),(2),(5),(4),(5), (8), (1), (3), (6),(9)]

Stage 4: According to the difference between them ONE member of each dyad (with 6 being the exception) will receive a weighting; this is pre-determined in the following map:

```
getWeightDiretion :: Map.Map Integer Integer -- determine weight direction 
getWeightDirection = Map.fromList $
 [(1, -1),
  (2, -1), 
  (3, 1),
  (4, 1),
  (5, -1),
  (6, 0),
  (7, 1),
  (8, -1),
  (9, -1),
  (10, 1),
  (11, 1),
  (12, 1))]
```

As stated if the value of map lookup is 1 weight goes to bottom; -1 to top. The problem is when looking up key is 6 when *neither* of the dyad members are weighted more than the other: that is, they receive *weight equally*. The weightings are also predetermined by looking keys up in this map:

```
schemaCAT :: Map.Map Integer Double  --Cross-At-Tail weighting scheme
schemaCAT = Map.fromList $
[(12, 0.985),
 (11, -0.7),
 (10, 0.2),
 (9, 0.4), 
 (8, 0.6),
 (7, 0.9),
 (6, 0.08),
 (5, 0.8),
 (4, 0.7),
 (3, 0.5),
 (2, 0.1),
 (1, -0.8),
 (999, 0.25)]
```

The input to the allocateWeights function is in the form [[(-1, 6), (0, 3)], [.... where the first member of each tuple in each sub-list is a transposing factor - which is not relevant here; the second is one of a permutation pair. Each sub-list in the input represents one permutation. The allocateWeights function operates on x!!1 of each tuple in each sub-list directly.

After applying the above I should end up with a list a tuples [(-1, 3, 0.5)....] The second tuple member is the member of the tuple that receives the weight and the third is the weight itself (I'll leave out what the first member of the tuple is as is not important. The same with key 999 which is a special case).

As far as I understand it I have two problems. First, maps return Maybes and using these values in guards is problematic, Second, is the issue of using two definitions on the right hand side of an expression in a guard. Still struggling with 'Justs' and 'Maybes' :(

THX....

Comment: You can return a list of two items, or a 2-tuple if there are always two results.

Comment: Your second and third guards will never be matched because if direction is <= Just 0 it is also <= Just 1 and the first guard already matched.

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of behaviour you want here. Please give some examples.

Comment: How would you write the result in the non-idiomatic way, i.e., without trying to reuse `assignBottom` and `assignTop`?

Comment: The guards can returning anything, as long as every guard returns a value of the same type. What is the combination of `(head x, last x, weight)` and `(head y, last y, weight)` supposed to look like?

Comment: I am going to cut out the non-essentials its going to cloud the issue.

Comment: I'm very confused where `(-1, 7, 0.5)` comes from.  `7` isn't an element of your original list or part of your dyads or even a difference.  And `0.5` is the weight at key `3` -- how is that related to `7`?  Also, despite your further explanation, you haven't answered @chepner's question of what a "combination" is supposed to look like.  Perhaps give example expected _inputs and outputs_ for your function (including at 6).  (Also, are there two different functions `allocateWeight` and `allocateWeight'` or is that a typo in your code?)

Comment: I've changed 7 to 3. The absolute difference of the two first tuple members (6,3)  i.e. 3 (weighted  0.5)  this being assigned to the lowest member of of the (6,3) pair. Ive removed the typo in the allocateWeight declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure how you intend to combine the results when you write “assignBottom *and* assignTop”, but I can offer a few suggestions that may help.

When you find yourself in a situation like this, with a tangle of primitive types that are frustrating to work with, it’s usually a sign that you’re trying to do too many things at once in a single function, and that you need to introduce auxiliary functions or data types and compose them to solve the problem. When I look at this code:

```
allocateWeight :: [[Integer]] -> (Integer, Integer, Maybe Double)
allocateWeight' [x, y]
    |direction <= Just 1 = assignBottom
    |direction <= Just (-1)  = assignTop
    |direction <= Just 0 = (?? assignBottom and assignTop ??)
  where diff = (abs(x!!1 - y!!1))
      direction = Map.lookup diff getWeightDirection 
      weight = Map.lookup diff schemaCAT
      assignBottom = (head x, last x, weight)
      assignTop = (head y,  last y, weight)
```

What jumps out at me are the following:

- Is it `allocateWeight` or `allocateWeight'`?
- The input is `[[Integer]]`, but you say that the inner lists are known to be “dyads”, so this list probably wants to be a list of pairs `[(Integer, Integer)]`.
- Furthermore, `allocateWeight` assumes that there are only two elements in the *outer* list with the pattern `[x, y]`. Is this function meant to operate on the *whole* list, or *each* pair in the list?
- The result type `(Integer, Integer, Maybe Double)`, doesn’t explain its meaning; it would benefit from being a `data` type.
- A series of guards `direction <= Just …` suggests that you want to first pattern-match on the `Maybe` value and then compare its range.
- Your guard values are overlapped. Guards are checked in order, `Nothing` compares less than `Just x` for any `x`, and `Just x <= Just y` if `x <= y`. So if the value isn’t found, `Nothing` will compare less than `Just 1` and the first guard will be taken; and if the value compares less than or equal to `Just (-1)` or `Just 0`, then it must *already* have compared less than or equal to `Just 1`, so the other two guards will never fire.
- `diff = (abs(x!!1 - y!!1))` again suggests that these don’t want to be lists; the indexing operator `!!` is best avoided in ordinary code. (It does have some use in cases where, for example, you’re using a list for memoisation, but that’s for another time.)
- The weight directions are always `-1`, `0`, or `1`, which is asking to be a `data` type.
- The returned weight probably shouldn’t be wrapped in a `Maybe`.

So just in terms of code organisation, here’s how I would approach this:

```
-- A pair of a value with a weight.
data Weighted a = Weighted a Double
  deriving (Show)

-- The direction in which to weight a pair.
data WeightDirection
  = WeightBottom
  | WeightTop
  | WeightBoth

-- Use data type instead of integer+comment.
getWeightDirection :: Map.Map Integer WeightDirection
getWeightDirection = Map.fromList
  [ (1, WeightTop)
  , (2, WeightTop) 
  , (3, WeightBottom)
  , (4, WeightBottom)
  , (5, WeightTop)
  , (6, WeightBoth)
  -- …
  ]

-- Allocate weights for a single pair.
allocateWeight :: (Integer, Integer) -> [Weighted Integer]
allocateWeight (x, y) = case Map.lookup diff getWeightDirection of

  Just direction -> case Map.lookup diff schemaCAT of
    Just weight -> case direction of
      WeightBottom -> [Weighted x weight]
      WeightTop -> [Weighted y weight]
      WeightBoth -> [Weighted x weight, Weighted y weight]

    -- What do you want to do in this case?
    Nothing -> error ("direction for " ++ show diff ++ " not found")

  -- What do you want to do if the difference isn’t found?
  -- Raise an error like this, or return a default?
  Nothing -> error ("weight for " ++ show diff ++ " not found")
  where
    diff = abs (x - y)
```

I’ve guessed that when you want to allocate weight “equally” to both values, that you want to include both values in the result, each with their own weight, so I’ve changed `allocateWeight` to return a list. If you want to *combine* the weights in a different way, say, `(x * weight / 2 + y * weight / 2)` or something like that, then you may not need that. Using lists, as to your particular question, you could also write: `bottom = [Weighted x weight]` and `top = [Weighted y weight]`, and then return `bottom`, `top`, or their concatenation `bottom ++ top` as needed.

But this illustrates what I want to show: with this function for operating on a single pair, you can compute the results for a whole list of pairs by `map`ping it over the input list and `concat`enating the results, using those functions separately or using `concatMap`:

```
          allocateWeight ::  (Integer, Integer)  ->  [Weighted Integer]

      map allocateWeight :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> [[Weighted Integer]]

concatMap allocateWeight :: [(Integer, Integer)] ->  [Weighted Integer]
```

You may be asking: what happened to the “extra” values you were keeping alongside each pair? The answer is that this function shouldn’t be concerned with them; generally the approaches are to extract the portions you need (with `map` or similar) and recombine the results (e.g. using `zipWith` prior to `concat`), or parameterise this function so it can only see the portions of a value that it needs, e.g.:

```
allocateWeightBy :: (a -> Integer) -> (a, a) -> [Weighted a]
allocateWeightBy getValue (x, y) = …

  -- Since ‘x’ has a polymorphic type, it enforces that
  -- the only thing you can do with it is call ‘getValue’
  -- or return it in the list of weighted values.
```

The other thing is that if you’re struggling with `Maybe` results from looking up keys that may not be present in a `Map`, you may just need practice, but you could also benefit from trying different approaches, like:

- Use `case` wherever you have a lookup to explicitly handle the absence of a value. It’s verbose but it works and can be made more idiomatic later.
- If the `Nothing` case should raise an error, use the unsafe indexing operator `(Data.Map.!)`. (Like `!!` this can be a sign of poor data structuring, and can bite you later.)
- If you just want to provide a default value, use functions like `fromMaybe` found in `Data.Maybe`, e.g. `fromMaybe (defaultWeight :: Double) (maybeWeight :: Maybe Double) :: Double`.
- Use a function instead of a `Map`, with a fallthrough case for a key that’s not found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Trying to accomplish too much all at once when coding is a problem I am not unacquainted with!! I will consider your answer carefully..

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to ditch numerical values for data types. In actual fact I previously coded a version of the project in  Java where I used: enum root (BOTTOM , INVERSION, INDEFINITE, NULL) to determine weight direction. I am still relatively unfamiliar with Haskell particularly with regard to typing so was unaware of the possibility of porting over this same approach. Thx again anyways...